# How to export MongoDB collection using library pymongo (python)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I do not have much experience, I looked at many articles, the result did not lead to anything. I have a small collection (85 documents), I need to export it using python. Yes, it was him. If there are no problems with inserting documents, setting indexes, then here they appeared.

As I understand it is necessary to use the method `find`.
Here's an example document of a collection.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6012b7e0fe7371258899441e"}, "date":"2021-01-23","confirmed":12638,"deaths":113,"recovered":10710,
"region_name":"Республика Адыгея",
"region_code":"RU-AD","isolation_start":"16.07.2020 21:58:11",
"level":3,"self_isolation":null}
```

How is it necessary to make transformations in order to get csv? If it doesn't make it difficult, can I have a code example?

Comment: why don't you try `pandas`? You fetch all documents then read it in pandas` then use `pandas.to_csv()`

Comment: @Epsi95, I tried, but in the end, for some reason, the skill did not work, I added the method that I did in the answer. I would be glad if you explain to me how to use the pandas in this case.

Comment: @Epsi95, I figured out how to do it, apparently sat at the monitor and stupid for a long time. thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I sat at the monitor. I did two ways, maybe someone will need it.

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test_import
collection = db.myimport2

csv_columns = ['_id','date','confirmed', 'deaths', 'recovered', 'region_name', 'region_code', 'isolation_start', 'level', 'self_isolation']

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for post in collection.find():
        writer.writerow(post)
```

and pandas

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test_import
collection = db.myimport2

df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))

df.to_csv('mycsvfile2.csv')
```